# On Shabbos, can you pick up a pair of soiled underwear to put it in the hamper?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh, personal-hygiene

If one unfortunately soils his underpants on Shabbat, when he goes to the bathroom to remove the soiled underpants, can he then pick up the underpants in order to put them in the dirty laundry, or would they be *muktzeh machmas mi'us* and therefore he would be forbidden to pick them back up?

Comment: http://halachahbyemail.blogspot.com/2012/12/evaluating-graf-shel-rei.html

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Jared and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 11):

In this situation the application of *graf shel rei* (bedpan) would apply. The Shulchan Aruch  [Orach Chayim 308:35](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%97_%D7%9C%D7%94) allows one to move a *graf shel rei* out of sight or smell . This is a special *halacha* which allows one to move something which one would usually not be allowed to move since it has no use, but since it is something which is disgusting and unsightly that item becomes permissible to clear away.